# Using () (and other zero-sized types) in FFI

Tags: rust, ffi

What's the equivalent of `()` (or any other [zero-sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#zero-sized-types-zsts)) when doing FFI in Rust? Specifically, I'm curious what the most reasonable equivalent of `()` as a function argument when writing an `extern "C"` function.

My understanding is that zero-sized types are not valid in C, but Rust seems to allow them in `extern "C"` functions, for example:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn test_ffi(input: ()) -> () {
}
```

In this case, returning `()` is the same as declaring a `void` function in C#. However, it's not clear to me how you would declare the `input` argument when generating the binding from C. I was under the impression that ZSTs aren't representable in C, and so shouldn't be FFI-safe. It seems like the [nomicon confirms this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#representing-opaque-structs), saying:

> And to avoid warning around using `()` in FFI, we instead use an empty array (`[u8; 0]`), which works just as well as an empty type but is FFI-compatible.

Which seems to imply that `()` isn't FFI-compatible, but that `[u8; 0]` is (even though I'd expect it to also be zero-size)?

Comment: Just to confirm: a zero-length type is invalid in C, so you cannot (should not) use a Rust ZST in a C FFI situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `()` in C. Some could argue `void` is equivalent but that's actually not the case.  Of course they have similarities, in most cases they are interchangeable like you said: `pub extern "C" fn test_ffi() -> ()` will correctly be interpreted as `void test_ffi(void)`. (NB: here `void` inside the parameter list means the function takes no arguments so it is not an empty type).

You can think of `void` as *nothing*, but is `()` nothing? No, it's an empty tuple, while `void` is actually just nothing.

> I was under the impression that ZSTs aren't representable in C, and so shouldn't be FFI-safe.

No, they are not representable in C: `pub extern "C" fn test_ffi(input: (), foo: i32) -> ()` here is unclear what the Rust compiler should understand because `void test_ffi(void, int32_t foo);` is invalid in C.

[Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#representing-opaque-structs) uses an empty array to make types opaque. I would not recommend that but it could be okay for this specific use case. Opaque types in C are evil anyway. Note that empty arrays are illegal in C so they should only be used on the Rust side.

I would advise to never use any zero sized type in any FFI.

Comment: Thanks! Confirming that ZSTs aren't valid in C FFI (beyond `()` being a special case as a return type) was mostly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Void has overloaded meaning in C/C++. It can mean a function takes no arguments or returns nothing, or it can be a `void*`, a pointer to some data but without saying what that data is.

For the former case, for functions that return nothing or take no arguments, just omit them in your function description. A function that returns nothing is technically returning `()`, but it doesn't need to be explicitly written. The *unit type* serves the same purpose as `void` in this case even though unit is *something* rather than *nothing*.

For the latter case of `void*`, the [winapi-rs](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs) crate defines a [c_void](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/0.3/src/lib.rs#L37) to be an empty enum and then uses `mut *c_void` or `const *c_void` as the type for arguments and structs which use a void pointer.